# How to select a specific vertex in UV unwrapping?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to UV unwrap one of my objects.

My problem is that I can't select a vertex in the UV window when it is at the edge of a Cut (Marked seam). Instead, it automatically selects the vertex on the other side of the cut.

[[image]][1]

The red arrow indicates the vertex I selected. the blue circle indicates the vertex that gets selected.

Can someone tell me what the problem is here?

---

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, then write an answer with the *answer your own question* button.

Comment: sorry i'm new here. --> done

Answer (score 5):

Just after I posted this question, I found the answer myself.

I had this Button enabled
[image]

"Keep UV and edit mode mesh in sync"